# Perl wont recognize my if statement

Tags: perl

my code:

```
          #!/usr/bin/perl
          $line = <STDIN>;
          if ($line eq "/n") {
              print "That was just a blank line!";
          } else {
              print "That line of input was: $line";
          }
```

it wont recognize when $line in empty or /n. it will just output "That line of input was:" and then it will be nothing, empty. but it will print text if $line actually is something.

Answer (score 4):

It's `"\n"` to create a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather try  the following so that it matches the blank lines with empty spaces

```
if ($line =~ /^\s+$/)
```

Comment: Or more simply `if (not $line =~ /\S/)`

Comment: @TLP you could also make that `if ($line !~ /\S/)`

Comment: @sim That is correct. You could also use `unless`. I often find that `!~` is easy to confuse with its opposite.